# Perl - How do I count and print occurrences of domains in email address array?

Tags: arrays, perl, count, unique

I have been struggling with this for a couple days now and cannot seem to figure it out.

I have an array of email addresses that were created via `push(@emails,$email)` in a while loop.

I am attempting to **create a list of unique domains with occurrence count of each** in the array.

**Ordered by number of occurrences.**

So, if the array `@emails` has:

`john@yadoo.com ringo@geemail.net george@zoohoo.org paul@yadoo.com`

I can print:

```
yadoo.com 2
geemail.net 1
zoohoo.org 1
```

I found this example based on emails in a file but, WAY over my head. Can someone help me in a more verbose code example that can be used with an array of email addresses?

```
perl -e 'while(<>){chomp;/^[^@]+@([^@]+)$/;$h{$1}++;}
foreach $k (sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h)  {print $h{$k}." ".$k."\n";} infile
```

I also tried: (more to my level of lack of understanding)

```
foreach my $domain (sort keys %$domains) {
  print "$domain"."=";
  print $domains->{$domain}."\n";
};
```

AND

```
my %countdoms;
$countdoms{$_}++ for @domains;
print "$_ $countdoms{$_}\n" for keys %countdoms;
```

The best result I got of many different attempts was a total count (which was 1812 (accurate count) with a number 2 next to it. I am close, possibly?

Comment: P.S. I split domains off first in last two above examples eg: `$domain = split('\@',$email); push(@domains,$domain);` in a loop but, need complete example including the split if needed to avoid confusing me even more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your email address populated in an array this'll get you a count for each domain.  I'm sure someone can produce something prettier!

```
my @emails = ('john@yadoo.com','ringo@geemail.net','george@zoohoo.org','paul@yadoo.com');

my %domainCount;

foreach(@emails){
    if ($_ =~ /@(\w+.*)/){
        $domainCount{$1}++;
    }
}

for my $domain (sort { $domainCount{$b} <=> $domainCount{$a}} keys %domainCount ){
    print "$domain - $domainCount{$domain}\n";
}
```

Comment: he says: "Ordered by number of occurrences"

Comment: Now sorting output into descending order

Comment: PERFECT! How do you do that so fast? Thank you. I will study and learn what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving you another answer, let me explain you what your code example is doing:

```
while(<>){chomp;/^[^@]+@([^@]+)$/;$h{$1}++;}
foreach $k (sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h)  {print $h{$k}." ".$k."\n";}
```

The first line counts the domains from emails in files.

`while(<>)` iterates over the input files line by line. The input files are the file(s) passed as arguments or stdin if no arguments were passed. Each line is placed in `$_`.

`chomp;` simply removes the newline from the end of `$_`.

`/^[^@]+@([^@]+)$/` is the regular expression that parses out the domain and is applied to `$_`. It checks for something that has no '@' in the first part, then a '@' and then no '@' in the last part. It remembers the last part, which will be stored in `$1`. `^` and `$` stand for the beginning and the end of the string, respectively.

`$h{$1}++;` uses the domain (in `$1`) to increment the count in the hash `%h`. This works even if it's not present, because `undef` behaves here like 0.

In order to make this work for your list, you can just do

```
foreach(@emails) {/^[^@]+@([^@]+)$/;$h{$1}++;}
```

The second line prints the domains from the hash `%h`.

`sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h` returns a list of domains sorted by descending occurrence by using the comparison function `$h{$b} <=> $h{$a}` to look up the count. Note that it's b <=> a, not a <=> b, this makes it descending.

The rest of line 2 prints out the result.

Comment: Thank you. This is very valuable to me.  Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit crude because I am rusty on Perl but this should do the job:

```
use strict;
$|=1;
my ($dom, %hsh);
my @arr = ('john@yadoo.com', 'ringo@geemail.net', 'george@zoohoo.org', 'paul@yadoo.com');
foreach (@arr) {
    ($dom) = ($_ =~ /.*\@(.*)$/);
    $hsh{$dom}++;
}
foreach (keys %hsh) {
    print ("$_:$hsh{$_}\n");
}
```

Comment: This worked but, not in order but, thank you so much. Helps me to understand.

Comment: Just add 'sort' just before 'keys'.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array 
    = qw<john@yadoo.com ringo@geemail.net george@zoohoo.org paul@yadoo.com>
    ;
my %dom_count;
$dom_count{ $_ }++ foreach map { ( split '@' )[-1] } @array;
foreach my $pair ( 
    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] or $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } 
    map  { [ $_ => $dom_count{ $_ } ] } keys %dom_count 
    ) { 
    print "@$pair\n";
}
```

Comment: the keys are the domains here, there is no sense of sorting them, I guess you wanted to use sort with <=>

Comment: Thank you, This works as well but, not listed in order. Very good and uses map which shows me how to do that! What a learning experience! THANK YOU!